# Why isn't Google Maps reloading with new coordinates, with the rest of list detail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-redux

I have a list of events, and each event has a click function that displays the details of that event. Each detail holds a google map which takes the latlng coordinates found inside the clicked event object.

My problem is this: when I click on an event for the first time, the detail comes out correctly, with the correct title, location name and map. But then, the second click renders the new detail of the new event with the correct title, location name BUT the map doesn't change.

Why isn't the map being reloaded with the new coordinates?

here is the code for the 'event list' container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { selectEvent } from '../actions/index.js';

class EventsList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var createEventsList = this.props.events.map((event, i) => {
            return <li key={i} onClick={() => this.props.selectEvent(event)}>{event.title}</li>
        });
        return(
            <ul>{createEventsList}</ul>    
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        events: state.events
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ selectEvent: selectEvent }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EventsList);
```

the code for the 'event detail' container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import GoogleMap from '../components/google_map.js';

class EventDetail extends React.Component{
    render() {
        if(!this.props.event) {
            return <div>Pick an Event</div>
        }
        const latcoord = parseFloat(this.props.event.locationLat);
        const longcoord = parseFloat(this.props.event.locationLong);


        return(
            <div>
                <div>details for:</div>
                <div>{ this.props.event.title }</div>
                <div>{ this.props.event.location }</div>
                <GoogleMap long={longcoord} lat={latcoord}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        event: state.eventDetail
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventDetail);
```

and here is the code for the Google Map component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class GoogleMap extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
            zoom: 15, 
            center: {
                lat: this.props.lat,
                lng: this.props.long
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="google-map" ref="map"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since componentDidMount gets called only once when the component is mounted, when you click on an event for the second time, the map is not getting updated. To correct this you will need to implement componentDidUpdate() function. Also you should save the map in a state or in this context. You wouldn't want to create a new map always.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
            zoom: 15, 
            center: {
                lat: this.props.lat,
                lng: this.props.long
            }
        });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
       this.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(this.props.lat, this.props.lng));
}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! this was really helpful

Comment: Please accept the answer if the solution worked for you. :)